# MySQL query count returning wrong value

Tags: mysql

So, this query returns result 1 even if there is no tasks related to list. How to fix it so it returns 0 for lists with zero tasks?

```
SELECT 
  l.list_id, l.list_name, l.list_time_created, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.task_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS numberOfTasks,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.task_completed IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t.task_completed END) AS numberOfCompletedTasks
FROM list l
LEFT JOIN task t ON l.list_id = t.list_id 
WHERE l.user_id = ':user_id'
GROUP BY l.list_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no tasks, then the rows will be filtered out.  You want a `left join`:

```
SELECT l.list_id, l.list_name, l.list_time_created,
       COUNT(t.task_id ) AS numberofTasks,
       SUM(t.task_completed = 1) AS numberofCompletedTasks
FROM list l LEFT JOIN
     task t
     ON l.list_id = t.list_id 
WHERE l.user_id = ':user_id'
GROUP BY l.list_id;
```

I introduced table aliases.  These make a query easier to write and to read.

I also simplified the logic for `numberofCompletedTasks`.  Your original formulation is fine (and even standard SQL), but MySQL has a nice short-cut.

Comment: It works beautiful. The problem was with SUM and COUNT expressions. Written this way the result is as expected. Thank you very much sir!